# unable to send e-mail using firebase google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, flask, npm, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

**I have tried firebase cloud functions to send e-mail when something write(change) in firebase real-time-database.**

```js
/**
 * Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/answers-evaluation-e5468/answers').onWrite(async (change) => {
  const snapshot = change.after;
  const val = snapshot.val();

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Answers-Evaluation()" <xyz@gmail.com>',
    to: val.email,
  };

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = 'Dear ' + val.Name;  //for example
  mailOptions.text = val.a1, val.a2, val.a3, val.result1, val.result2, val.result3;

 try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('email sent to:', val.email);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email, please check the email:', error);
  }
  return null;
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Data Set Collecting</title>
    <script>
        function showAlert() {
            alert("Response noted! Submit another Response!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="text-center">
<form class="form-signin" action="{{ url_for("foo") }}" method="post">
    <div class="container">

        <br>
        <h6 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Question1 :</h6>
        <br>
        <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">What is Encapsulation? Give Example.</h3>
        <br>
        <textarea name="first" rows="5" cols="100" title="Answer"></textarea><!--name=id -->
        <br>

        <br>
        <h6 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Question2 :</h6>
        <br>
        <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Define Asymptotic Notation and list its types.</h3>
        <br>
        <textarea name="second" rows="5" cols="100" title="Answer"></textarea>
        <br>


        <br>
        <h6 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Question3 :</h6>
        <br>
        <h3>What is Polymorphism ? List its Types.</h3>
        <br>
        <textarea name="third" rows="5" cols="100" title="Answer"></textarea>
        <br>

        <br>

        <input type="email" placeholder="Email ID*" name="emailID">
        <input type="Class" placeholder="Your Class*" name="Class">
        <input type="USN" placeholder="Your USN*" name="USN">
        <input type="Name" placeholder="Your Name*" name="Name">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showAlert()">

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I referred this firebase app for cloud function [github link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users),
and this is how my .JSON [Real-time-databse child notes] file looks like.

```
 {
  "answers" : {   
 "-MM_KOHhbRjgN12YQsHI" : {
      "Class" : "x",
      "Name" : "xsxsxs",
      "USN" : "xsx",
      "a1" : "sdfsgdsfgggesrgsrd",
      "a2" : "gssfgsrgsrg",
      "a3" : "rgesrdgsrdgaewr",
      "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
      "result1" : 0,
      "result2" : 0,
      "result3" : 0
    },
```

**[I deployed functions in GCP, but the trigger is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzSFt.png)**
is there any field in .Javascript or in .html should I change to get my function working?

when I tested the cloud function in GCP by giving the .JSON code, following error is noticed :
***Error: function execution failed. Details:
Cannot read property 'email' of null***

Comment: It looks like you didn't do `TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sir, I did  using the following command ... " firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="myusername@gmail.com" gmail.password="secretpassword" "

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you've done to configure and run this code, including what you said in that comment.  We should be able to copy what you have and observe the same result.  You should also log the values in your function code to confirm that everything is set the way you expect.  Right now, the error message suggests that your email is not actually configured the way you think.

Comment: @DougStevenson sir, I have clearly given the error, code, procedure .please help me this { email is not actually configured the way you think}.